# Regex to match JSON Web Token within URL

Tags: php, regex, jwt

I need a little help refining this regex to be able to identify a JWT token within an URL string using PHP. This matches a token fine but not if I append another URI segment.

Regex so far:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+?\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+?\.([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$/
```

URL this works for:

```
http://not.website.com/**eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ**
```

URL it doesn't work for (note additional segments on the end)

```
http://not.website.com/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ/additional/segments
```

The expected match should look like:

```
http://not.website.com/**eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ**/additional/segments
```

Comment: try remove the final dollar.

Comment: if that jwt is intended to be the first "query" segment in url, then you actually don't need any regexp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on where these URL strings occur (in a text or standalone), you could [simply do](https://regex101.com/r/pP4dB8/1):

```
^https?://.+?/(?P<token>[^/\n\r]+)
```

In `PHP`, this would be:

```
$string = 'http://not.website.com/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ/additional/segments';
$regex = '~                     # delimiter
          ^https?://.+?/        # match http:// or https:// + anything up to a / lazily
          (?P<token>[^/\n\r]+)  # capture everything that is not a / or newline (for this demo) to the group "token"
          ~x';                  # delimiter
preg_match($regex, $string, $match);
echo $match["token"];           # access your token in the $match array
// output: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/JAjNhj).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly

Comment: @MikeMiller: Glad to be of any help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can ammend your regex in this manner

> [a-zA-Z0-9-_]+?.[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+?.([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)[/a-zA-Z0-9-_]+?$

Add

**[/a-zA-Z0-9-_]*?** before **$**

(optional:(*?) so extra forward slashes and characters will be covered in above pattern)

Comment: I believe it's `\.` cause plain `.` mean any character except line terminators.

But `\.` mean literally "."

Answer (score 0):

```
/(http:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+)(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+)(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)*$/
```

Your token will be extracted from second group
See https://regex101.com/r/fO9dR4/1